# How can i debug discord js bot?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have make a simple script to test my bot.
Bot started and I show "is online" on discord and log a message.

But why when I type a command, bot not sending any message?

```
const Discord   = require("discord.js")
const client    = new Discord.Client()

let token = "xxx";

client.login(token)
client.on("ready", ready => {
    console.log("Bot lancé avec succès 10 !")
    client.user.setActivity("IN DEVELOPPEMENT")
});


client.on("message", message => {
  if (message.content === "!ping") {
       console.log("Bot lancé avec succès 111111 !")
    message.channel.send("Pong.")
  }
})
```

Is there a reason why this is not working? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Message based commands are no longer recommended as a way to interact with Discord bots. You can see how to set up slash commands using this [discord.js official guide](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/slash-commands.html), you can see the official guide for responding to slash commands [here](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/command-handling.html).

If you would like to still set up an event listener for messages and respond to them your message listener code should look like this:

```
client.on("messageCreate", message => {
  if (message.content === "!ping") {
    console.log("Bot lancé avec succès 111111 !")
    message.channel.send("Pong.")
  }
```

The reason it did not work is because you were listening to the event `message` which does not exist, the event `messageCreate` on the other-hand does exist and is emitted whenever a user sends a message.

Comment: hello i have test your code but not working.

```client.on("messageCreate", message => {
  if (message.content === "!ping") {
    console.log("Bot lancé avec succès 111111 !")
    message.channel.send("Pong.")
  }```

All is ok, why i not receive pong message when i type !ping

TY

Comment: You need to update your Gateway Intents as detailed here in the [discord.js official guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#privileged-intents). The intent you need is `MessageContent` @ArthurGorbana

Comment: ```const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({
 intents: [
  GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
 ],
});```

I have this error : **TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'MessageContent')**

Comment: I have node 16.x